# Find cumulative maximum of a pandas series, but reset the cumulative maximum when 0 is encountered

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the series below:

1. 100
2. 102
3. 101
4. 103
5. 0
6. 12
7. 123
8. 14

I want the result to be as follows:

1. 100
2. 102
3. 102
4. 103
5. 0
6. 12
7. 123
8. 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `d` be the variable containing your series, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the cummulative sum of `d == 0` and then obtain the [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)

```
d.groupby(d.eq(0).cumsum()).cummax()
Out[37]: 
0    100
1    102
2    102
3    103
4      0
5     12
6    123
7    123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had tried cummax and other functions but had no progress, this logic works like a charm.